# C++ with spacemacs_

Tags: spacemacs

I code in C++ using VIM, but would love to try spacemacs.  My install is fresh, no custom configurations yet.  So looking at `https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Blang/c-c%2B%2B`, a line, `(setq-default dotspacemacs-configuration-layers '(c-c++))` needs to be added to `.spacemacs`, but where can it be added?  Looking the snippet inside the `defun dotspacemacs/layers ()`, there is a comment that user code should not be added to this function, but then there is another section:

```
dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
'(
 ;; ----------------------------------------------------------------
 ;; Example of useful layers you may want to use right away.
 ;; Uncomment some layer names and press <SPC f e R> (Vim style) or
 ;; <M-m f e R> (Emacs style) to install them.
 ;; ----------------------------------------------------------------
 ;; auto-completion
 ;; better-defaults
 emacs-lisp
 ;; git
 ;; markdown
 ;; org
 ;; (shell :variables
 ;;        shell-default-height 30
 ;;        shell-default-position 'bottom)
 ;; spell-checking
 ;; syntax-checking
 ;; version-control
 )
```

so can I assume that I should add the line `(setq-default dotspacemacs-configuration-layers '(c-c++))` into the the `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers` block?  Or where should I add the line.  Then what do I do afterwards?

Comment: The docs are a bit misleading on this point. You just need to add `c-c++` to this list, for example you can put it after `emacs-lisp`. Then you either press `SPC f e R` or restart Emacs to install the new layer.

Comment: @user1135541 you could ask it in the gitter chat or issue tracker of Spacemacs.

Answer (score 2):

The code you've quoted is incomplete; you've chopped off the head of the form. In lisp all expressions are surrounded by parens, and the first element of such a list is the name of a function to call. Although I don't use spacemacs, I imagine that the part you chopped off was `(setq` or `(setq-default`. This is setting a variable to a value which is a quoted list (quoted lists look like `'(foo bar baz)`). It is, in fact, setting the same variable that the documentation on the c++ mode told you to set. You could include both of them in the file, one after the other, but the second would overwrite the changes made by the first. You should instead combine them. Just add `c-c++` to the existing list alongside  `emacs-lisp` and the commented-out suggestions.